# Open file with cygwin emacsclient?

Tags: windows, cygwin, emacsclient

How can I associate files in windows so they open in my running emacs using emacsclient?

I can only find some [old posts](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-08/msg00398.html) mentioning `emacsclient-w32` which seems to have been discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

#### I can only find some old posts mentioning emacsclient-w32 which seems to have been discontinued.

What makes you think it has been discontinued?

It can be found in the Cygwin emacs-w32-24.5-2 package:

[image: enter link description here]

You can always find out what packages contain particular Cygwin commands using [Search Packages](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi):

[image]

Note:

- There is also a version available for Cygwin x86 (32-bit Cygwin).

---

#### Integrating `emacs-32.exe` with Windows `explorer`

> I use the emacs-w32 package. It's probably the simplest/easiest to get working properly. Before you begin, you'll want to set a `HOME` environment value because it makes everything simpler.
>
> By default, Emacs on Windows uses `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\` as it's home directory. You can change this by right click on "Computer", choosing properties, clicking "Environment Variables.." and adding a new User variable called `HOME` that's equal to `C:\Users\<username>\`.
>
> **"Edit with Emacs" context option**
>
> Here's some registry keys to add a right-click context menu option "Edit with Emacs":
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\openWithEmacs]
> @="&Edit with Emacs"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\openWithEmacs\command]
> @="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\run.exe bash \"-l -c \\\"emacsclient -n \\\\\\\"$(cygpath \\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\" \\\"  \" "
> ```
>
> Yes, that's a lot of backslashes. This should handle all paths/filenames okay (spaces in paths are evil).

Source [Working "Edit with Emacs" context menu option for Cygwin Emacs and general Cygwin tips](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2c94mw/windows_working_edit_with_emacs_context_menu/)